# I want to back up my Ubuntu so that I can restore it like a new install OS

Tags: backup

Can I do this with pre-installed back-up application in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please follow the [guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. What did you try until now? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Remastersys is a tool which is able to create a LiveCD/Installation Media of your current system. It is not maintained anymore, but it still works for 14.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mutse-young/remastersys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remastersys-gtk
```